# What's the Perl equivalent of PHP's $_SERVER[...]?

Tags: perl, cgi

What's the Perl equivalent for the following PHP calls?

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Environment variables** are a series of hidden values that the web server sends to every CGI you run. Your CGI can parse them and use the data they send. Environment variables are stored in a hash called **%ENV**.

For example, `$ENV{'HTTP_HOST'}` will give the **hostname** of your server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print <<EndOfHTML;
<html><head><title>Print Environment</title></head>
<body>
EndOfHTML

foreach my $key (sort(keys %ENV)) {
    print "$key = $ENV{$key}<br>\n";
}

print "</body></html>";
```

For more details see **[CGI Environmental variables](http://www.cgi101.com/class/ch3/text.html)**

Answer (score 14):

Another way, than variable environement, is to use CGI :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ;

print CGI->new->url();
```

Moreover, it also offers a lot of CGI manipulation such
as accessing params send to your cgi, cookies etc...

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do this and use the variable $page_url.

```
my $page_url = 'http';
$page_url.='s' if $ENV{HTTPS};
$page_url.='://';
if($ENV{SERVER_PORT}!=80)
{
    $page_url.="$ENV{SERVER_NAME}:$ENV{SERVER_PORT}$ENV{REQUEST_URI}";
}
else
{
    $page_url.=$ENV{SERVER_NAME}.$ENV{REQUEST_URI};
}
```

Comment: PERFECTION :) Works great

Answer (score 2):

What's the environment you're working in? If it's CGI script try:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%ENV;
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks. Do you happen to know the Perl equivalent of the PHP function file_get_contents() as well? I've been playing around with open but can't get it to access a page on a different server the way file_get_contents() does.

Comment: @dandemeyere: What I usually did was: open FILE, $data = join'',<FILE>   then close FILE

Comment: hlynul's answer regarding file_get_contents is erroneous. dandemeyere asked (and had an answer for that question) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413151