# Perl equivalent of PHP's get_file_contents()?

Tags: php, perl, get, file-get-contents, lwp

The following PHP code does exactly what I want to do. The problem is I need to re-create it in Perl and I've been playing around with the `open()` and `sysopen()` Perl functions but can't do it. Does anyone have any help or know of any links that might help? Thanks.

```
$URL = "http://example.com/api.php?arguments=values";
echo file_get_contents($URL);
```

Comment: Have a lookt to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953707/in-perl-how-can-i-read-an-entire-file-into-a-string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of [LWP](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html):

```
use LWP::Simple;
$contents = get $URL or die;
print $contents;
```

Comment: obviously you don't need to store the contents. `use LWP::Simple; print get "http://google.com" or die;` and the `die` is a failsafe-exit

Comment: of course you could also just use `getprint()` : `use LWP::Simple; getprint("http://www.google.com") or die;`